# iOS w/ native Okta login - open link in embedded WKWebView

Tags: ios, swift, single-sign-on, okta

I have an iOS app, using a native login, based on the [custom example](https://github.com/okta/samples-ios/tree/master/custom-sign-in).

This works perfect and I am happy with it.

I have a requirement to open an embedded `WKWebView` within my app, that SSO’s a user in.

The url looks something like this:

https://{my-okta-org}.com/app/{some-okta-app-id}/exkms5nzsh0tD0kO10h7/sso/saml?RelayState={some-relay-state}

When I launch this however within my web view, I am redirected to an Okta login page. I would expect this really as the embedded view has no context of the authenticated session.

How can I set my session against this webview without asking the user to sign in again? As I have used the native login, I do not have a cookie set, so I suspect I will need to request one but am unsure of the flow required in this case.

Comment: iOS has some problems with cookies in Webviews
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/99674

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to not use WKWebView for SSO 1.Not secure, using javascript you can get user login and password 2.Cookies not share between your session and Safari(you are loosing all SSO magic) 3.WKWebView has problems with cookie synchronizing [Apple thread](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/99674) and you need manually manage your cookies

Comment: My username / password is not exposed to the webview. That happens as part of the native login. I'm also not aware of a JavaScript attack that can access the encrypted keychain on iOS device. 

Do you have a suggestion as to how I achieve this with OKTA?

Comment: @TeddyK you need to manually manage your cookies, save it after first sign in and then load it every time you launch your URL

Comment: I have a native login, there is no cookie set